# OpenSSL: cannot retrieve LIST via FTPS

Tags: c++, ssl, ftp, openssl, ftps

I'm developing a simple FTPS client in C++. The control channel communication is working over SSL just fine, but I'm having problems retrieving the file list. Currently I'm doing the following sequence:

```
open control connection
AUTH TLS
do handshake on control connection
USER username
PASS password
PBSZ 0
PROT P
EPSV
open data connection
TYPE A
LIST
read data connection
```

If I try to directly create an ssl connection (in open data connection phase), creating the connection fails. If I create a connection but perform the handshake only after LIST command is sent, the handshake succeeds but the client will not recieve any data from the server. This is my data connection opening logic (1 for directly ssl, 2 for handshake on demand):

```
SSL* ssl;
BIO* bioSsl;
int err;

SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
1) err = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
2) err = BIO_new_connect(host.c_str());
err = BIO_do_connect(bio);

2) bioSsl = BIO_new_ssl(ctx, 1);
2) bio = BIO_push(bioSsl, bio);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
```

Reading data connection is done using BIO_read() function. It always returns 0 (note: I'm able to read control socket and receive data this way). Existing clients are able to retrieve file list from the server, so the problem is not on the server side. Could anyone explain what is happening, am I doing something wrong in the sequence? Why does handshake on data connection fail, if it's initiated before LIST command? Any other advice also appreciated!

Comment: Hmm.  how are you managing your multiple sockets? `select`?  This smacks of an `SSL_pending`/`select` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. The problem was, that the server required reusing ssl sessions between control and data connection. It worked after adding (pseudocode)

```
SSL_SESSION s = SSL_get_session(controlSsl);
dataSsl = BIO_get_ssl(dataBio);
SSL_set_session(dataSsl, s);
```